# DotNetOpenAuth Post Issue - Bitbucket Deploy Keys

Tags: dotnetopenauth, bitbucket-api

I'm definitely banging my head against Oauth signed requests so am unsure if it's my code, DotNetOpenAuth or Bitbucket.

I'm trying to add a new deploy key as per

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/deploy-keys+Resource

I'm getting a `WebException` saying

`The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

Am I posting correctly with DotNetOpenAuth? I can't seem to find any good samples?

My code is follows:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"accountname", username},
                        {"key", Uri.EscapeDataString(key.PublicKey)}
                    };

var dataUrl = @"https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{0}/{1}/deploy-keys";
var url = string.Format(dataUrl, username, projectName);
var endpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(url, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest);
var request = _consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(endpoint, authToken, payload);

var payloadItems = from kvp in payload
            select kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value;
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join("&", payloadItems));

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

string responseString;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I get the feeling I just need a good sample of a form post using DotNetOpenAuth so apologies if it seems like i'm lazy; my google fu just isn't paying dividends.

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating your MessageReceivingEndpoint with the following:

```
new MessageReceivingEndpoint(url, HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest);
```